# Understanding derivation of expression for magnetic flux in cylinder from Ampere's law

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics

I'm looking at a paper using Biot-Savart and Ampere's law to determine the induced magnetic field within a conducting cylinder. By inserting

$$J_z = \frac{I}{2\pi} \int_0^\infty \lambda J_0(\lambda r) exp(-\lambda^2\sigma_j^2/4d) \frac{\sinh(\lambda(c-z))}{\sinh(\lambda c)}d\lambda$$

into

$$B_\theta = \frac{\mu_m}{r} \int_0^r r J_z dr $$

they obtain

$$B_\theta = \frac{\mu_mI}{2\pi} \int_0^\infty J_1(\lambda r) exp(-\lambda^2\sigma_j^2/4d) \frac{\sinh(\lambda(c-z))}{\sinh(\lambda c)}d\lambda$$

I'm having troubles to understand how they obtained the final expression for $B_\theta$. Can anyone help and explain it step by step?

Here, $B_\theta$ and $J_z$ are the magnetic flux and current density components in an axisymmetric domain (r, z, $\theta$). $\sigma_j$, $\mu_m$, c and d are constants, and $J_0$ and $J_1$ are Bessel functions.

Comment: In fact, they just use the well known integral $\int^x dx' x' J_0( x')=x J_1(x)+C$ which can be derived for example from the series representation of the Bessel functions

Comment: @tired That's dissapointingly simple ;) Thanks, please go ahead and put it down as proper answer.